# How to use transcrypt in Python

Tags: python, transcrypt

I'm trying to transpile some simple examples, as the turtle tree example (https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/tree/master/turtle), using Pyhton 3.7.6 and transcrypt 3.7.16.

Basically, I'm just putting the `.py` within a folder and transcrypting from `cmd` doing:

```
"python -m transcrypt -n turtle_tree.py";
```

Everything seems to be ok, no errors are shown. 
After that, I changed the line 20 of the `html` file writting 
`"_ _ target_ _/turtle_tree.js"`, as the output is not within `_ _ javascript_ _` folder.

When I open the `html` it opens blank.

Can anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong? And if someone can provide me some documentation about this library, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 20 should be replaced, obviously within script tags, by:

```
 type="module"> import * as turtle_tree from './__target__/turtle_tree.js'; window.turtle_tree = turtle_tree;
```

Then, from the cmd inside your folder, you have to open an http server:

```
python -m http.server
```

Finally, from your browser, you have to type:

```
http://localhost:8000/turtle_tree.html
```

It was as easy as following the Transcrypt docs v.v'

2.2. Your first Transcrypt program:
https://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/installation_use.html#your-first-transcrypt-program

Comment: I still have some questions. Why the html does not work by doubleclicking it as in previous versions?